# Pycharm Console Error - Not finding source files

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to configure the pycharm to my enviroment but the console simply doesn't work.
I've already tried the following from various posts:

1-Setting the interpreter to the new enviroment. Which works when I run outside the console:
[Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anv66.png)

2- I've set the environmental variables to the main folder and to the DLLs, Scripts and Libs
[Enviromental variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWaNg.png)

Regardless of that I'm still keep receiving the error message when I try to open the console:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui1bd.png)

I honestly don't know what else to try... I've also tried:

-To reinstall the whole thing
-Install the ssl packages again
-Create a new environment(conda and virtual). 
-Create a dummy project, set all patches again, delete the dummy and create a new one
Nothing works!

Apparently this is a common problem and every post I find has a different solution, but none worked for me so far.

I'm using Pycharm 2019.1

Comment: You might try running the Python console with just the Interpreter (no environment variables) first, then add the necessary env. vars.  I'm running PyCharm 2019.2.3 under CentOS 7 without any problems

Comment: Could you please try to update PyCharm? There had been many issues with activating conda environment that were fixed in 2019.1 and 2019.2.

Answer (score 0):

user2235698 Has Answered in the comments.

Installing the new version 2019.2.3 solved the problem.

Apparently there's no work around for the 2019.1 I was using before